# How to handle both save and save-as button with django class-based view

Tags: django, django-views

What I want to do is just a simple update view with two submit button: namely `save` which simply saves the update; and also `save-as` button, which of course save a copy of the updated form to the database and leave the original data unedited.

Now I know how to do this in function based view, provided that my `page_edit.html` has two button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name = "save" value="Save changes">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name = "save_as" value="Save as new Page">
```

Then my *simplified* view would be something along:

```
def page_edit(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'save' in request.POST:
            instance = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
        elif 'save_as' in request.POST:
            instance = Page.objects.create()
        p = PageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if p.is_valid():
            """write to db"""
            p.clean()
            p.save()

            context = {'form': p, 'p_data_in': p.cleaned_data, 'p': p.instance}
        return render(request, '/template/page_detail.html', context)

    else:
        instance = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
        p = PageForm(instance=instance)
        context = {'form': p, 'p': p.instance}
        return render(request, '/template/page_edit.html', context)
```

However, I'm a bit puzzled navigating with class-based view.

I tried using UpdateView in this way:

```
class PageEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    template_name = '/template/page_edit.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if 'save_as' in self.request.POST:
            # current = self.get_context_data()
            f = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            f.save()
        return super(PageEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

It does save a new instance to database. But it also change the current form, which supposedly left unedited.

I have a feeling this should be simple... but, since I'm new to class-based view, I'm quite struggling.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the instance has been updated because you have called `super` method, where changes has been saved(which is the original behavior. So you need to change it like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if 'save_as' in self.request.POST:
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)  # Just changing the instance of the form.
        form.is_valid()
    return super(PageEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```